# Error 193 debugging msi installer execution using cdb

Tags: windows, debugging, windows-installer

When trying to debug the installation process of a msi installer using CDB as, 
cdb -g -G -logo c:\log.log c:\temp\abc.msi
I get the following error saying 
"Cannot execute abc.msi", Win32 error On193 
"%1 is not a valid Win32 application." 
Debuggee initialization failed, Win32 error On193
"%1 is not a valid Win32 application"
There are no spaces in the path to the installer either.

Comment: An msi is not an executable; it is a package that gets processed by the installer subsystem (msiexec.exe).  I don't really know how to go about debugging it, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Image File Execution Options (IFEO) to have the OS launch a debugger and then have the debugger launch the debuggee. Under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options` create a key called `msiexec.exe`. In that new key create a REG_SZ value named `Debugger` and set that to `<path_to_cdb> -g -G -logo c:\log.log c:\temp\abc.msi`

Note: I normally use this with windbg.exe instead of cdb.exe. I think cdb.exe may need a command prompt already so try with windbg.exe or ntsd.exe.

Note2: You may want to remove the `-g` option so that you have a chance to set some breakpoints before execution begins.

You can find more info on IFEO in the debugger.chm help file that comes with Debugging Tools for Windows.